# add image invoice header / footer odoo 8

Tags: templates, odoo

I want to change the template invoices . I would like to insert a custom image in the header and footer .

```
<image x="1.3cm" y="27.7cm" height="40.0" width="19.0cm" >[[ company.logo or removeParentNode('image') ]]</image>
```

I want to change

```
<image x="1.3cm" y="27.7cm" height="40.0" width="19.0cm" >MY CUSTOM IMAGE</image>
```

how can I insert an image foreign type

```
<img src="my-custom-path">
```

In general, how can I import images ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom images importing it from a addons dir and add an image field routing it this dir.

```
<div class="footer">
         <img class="img img-responsive" src="/sale_order_report/static/src/img/header.jpg"/>
```